# Saving user interactions and presenting them

Tags: mysql, database, caching, nosql

I have a site where users vote on polls. They can also like these polls. When they scroll through their feed, the questions they've liked will be represented by a like icon being filled (kind of like Facebook or Instagram). Their votes will also be shown if they already voted for the polls on the generated feed.

As the website is scaling, getting their likes and votes to be queried for each question is taking a long time since there are now millions of votes. My question is how do I make this process faster? Currently, I use MySQL to store the data.

My thought is to use a cache store like Redis and store all their likes and votes for each question in this type of structure:

```
User_id:
  likes: [question_ids]
  votes: [question_ids]
```

where user_id is a dictionary key that contains values of array types. The feed gets loaded from the cache, for each question, we check if that question is liked or voted by the user. I'm not sure if this approach is the "best" or if there's another way of doing things. I'm wondering how Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc. save user interactions and how they query them.

Tables:

```
Question Table (simplified)
id   question   total_votes  total_likes

Choice Table  (One question has two choices)
id  question_id choice votes

Voting table
id  user_id  choice_id

Like Table
id  user_id  question_id
```

Query to get the newest questions:

```
SELECT  `core_question`.`id`, `core_question`.`user_id`,
        `core_question`.`status`,
        `core_question`.`total_votes`, `core_question`.`like_count`,
        `core_question`.`comment_count`, `core_question`.`created_at`,
        `core_question`.`slug`, `core_question`.`flag`,
        `core_question`.`spam_flag`,
        ( SELECT  U0.`is_liked`
            FROM  `core_like` U0
            WHERE (U0.`question_id` = `core_question`.`id`
              AND  U0.`user_id` = 1)
            LIMIT  1
        ) AS `like_selected`, 
        ( SELECT  U0.`choice_id`
            FROM  `core_voting` U0
            INNER JOIN  `core_choice` U1  ON (U0.`choice_id` = U1.`id`)
            WHERE (U1.`question_id` = `core_question`.`id`
              AND  U0.`user_id` = 1)
            LIMIT  1) AS `choice_selected`,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN `oauth_following`.`follower_id` = 1
                   THEN `oauth_following`.`id`
                   ELSE NULL END ) AS `is_following`
    FROM  `core_question`
    INNER JOIN  `oauth_user`  ON (`core_question`.`user_id` = `oauth_user`.`id`)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  `oauth_following`  ON (`oauth_user`.`id` =
                               `oauth_following`.`target_id`)
    WHERE  NOT (`core_question`.`user_id` IN (4, 5, 6, 7))
    GROUP BY  `core_question`.`id`
    ORDER BY  `core_question`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: Keeping just counts can be done relatively fast.  Keeping the details of 'who' liked 'what' is most costly, but may be practical.   Which do you need?

Comment: "Arrays" stored that way are very costly; don't do it.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.

Comment: @RickJames Thank you for your response. I've updated the question with how the tables look like. I'd like to keep the details of who liked what. For example, suppose you scroll through Instagram or Facebook and you've seen a post already that you already liked or voted for a poll, you'd expect to see your like or vote already there so that is why I need this in my situation.

Comment: Shouldn't `Voting` and `Liked` also have a `question_id` column?

Comment: Except for the `Question` table, `id` is not needed; there is a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY(question_id, choice) for `Choice`, etc.

Comment: Develop the `SELECTs`; this will help in designing the schemas.

Comment: @RickJames I'm using Django, so it's creating those ids automatically. Only liked has `question_id` I updated the schemas. `Voting` has only the `choice_id` and not the `question_id` to specify which choice the user cast their vote to. I also updated the question to include a sample query (queries are done in the Django ORM, but I converted to SQL for this example). The query returns the newest questions to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest these indexes:

```
core_question:    INDEX(user_id)
oauth_following:  INDEX(target_id,  follower_id)
core_like:        INDEX(question_id, user_id,  is_liked)
core_choice:      INDEX(question_id)
core_voting:      INDEX(user_id, choice_id)
```

Comment: Are the tables with multiple indexes like `core_like` for example, are the indexes separated or are they combined indexes. For example, is `question_id` an index, `user_id` an index, and `is_liked `an index, or are they one combined index?

Comment: @user2896120 - Composite, as I show, will be better for that query.